# Show Printers with specific name

Tags: vba, ms-access, printing, device-name

I have some code that lists all of the active printers (but does so in msgboxes rather than a list). I have no problem with that functionality. Here is the code below:

```
    If Printers.Count > 0 Then
    strMsg = "Printers installed: " & Printers.Count & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    For Each prtLoop In Application.Printers
        With prtLoop
           MsgBox .DeviceName                
      End With
    Next prtLoop
    Else
    MsgBox "No printers are installed."
    End If
```

While it does what I essentially need it to do I would like it to only popup if the printer that matches a partial of a printer name that is set in the code. For example if I have 3 printers:

```
Printer ABC 1
Printer ZZ5 2 (copy)
Printer 123
```

I want there to be an If Then statement probably after the

```
    For Each prtLoop In Application.Printers
```

portion of the code above that says if the device name is *ABC then it would only popup with "Printer ABC 1" instead of all 3.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for the help.
-Vladimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that is what you wanna do ?
`If Printers.Count > 0 Then
    strMsg = "Printers installed: " & Printers.Count & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    For Each prtLoop In Application.Printers
        With prtLoop
           If InStr(DeviceName, "ABC") Then 
              MsgBox .DeviceName

           End If

      End With
    Next prtLoop
    Else
    MsgBox "No printers are installed."
 End If`

edit: Access didn't like the If then statement because it was one line, error was coming up with "End If without Block If" error, I moved the MsgBox .DeviceName to its own line and it works.

Comment: Thank you Matthias!!! This works awesome. I did make a small change because Access threw up an error (End if without block if) because of MsgBox .Devicename being on the same line, after I moved it to its own line no more error and it worked fine.